# delegate_to ignores configured ssh_port

Tags: ssh, automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

**Use-Case**:
We are deploying virtual machines into a cloud with a default linux image (Ubuntu 22.04 at the moment). After deploying a machine, we configure our default users and change the SSH port from 22 to 2222 with Ansible.

Side note: We are using a jump concept through the internet - Ansible automation platform / AWS => internet => SSH jump host => target host

To keep the possibility for Ansible to connect to the new machine, after changing the SSH port, I found multiple Stack Overflow / blog entries, checking and setting `ansible_ssh_port`, basically by running `wait_for` on port 22 and 2222 and set the SSH variable depending on the result (code below).
Right now this works fine for the first SSH host (jumphost), but always fails for the second host due to issues with establishing the ssh connection.

Side note: The SSH daemon is running. If I use my user from the jump host, I can get a SSH response from 22/2222 (depending on the current state of deployment).

**Edit from questions**:

The deployment tasks should only be run on the target host. Not the jumphost as well.

I run the deployment on the jumphost first and make sure it is up, running and configured.

After that, i run the deployment on all machines behind the jumphost to configure them.

This also ensures that if i ever would need reboot, that i don't kill all tunneled ssh session by accident.

---

Ansible inventory example

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
  children:
    jumphosts:
      hosts:
        example_jumphost:
          ansible_host: 123.123.123.123
    cloud_hosts:
      hosts:
        example_cloud_host01: #local DNS is resolved on the jumphost - no ansible_host here (yet)
          ansible_ssh_common_args: '-oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q ansible@123.123.123.123 -p 2222"' #Tunnel through the appropriate jumphost
          delegation_host: "ansible@123.123.123.123" #delegate jobs to the jumphost in each project if needed

vars:
   ansible_ssh_port: 2222
```

SSH `check_port` role

```yaml
- name: Set SSH port to 2222
  set_fact:
    ansible_ssh_port: 2222

- name: "Check backend port 2222"
  wait_for:
    port: 2222
    state: "started"
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    connect_timeout: "5"
    timeout: "5"
#  delegate_to: "{{ delegation_host }}"
#  vars:
#    ansible_ssh_port: 2222
  ignore_errors: true
    register: ssh_port

- name: "Check backend port 22"
  wait_for:
    port: "22"
    state: "started"
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    connect_timeout: "5"
    timeout: "5"
#  delegate_to: "{{ delegation_host }}"
#  vars:
#    ansible_ssh_port: 2222
  ignore_errors: true
  register: ssh_port_default
  when: 
    - ssh_port is defined
    - ssh_port.state is undefined

- name: Set backend SSH port to 22
  set_fact:
    ansible_ssh_port: 22
  when: 
    - ssh_port_default.state is defined
```

The playbook itself

```yaml
- hosts: "example_cloud_host01"
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
  - role: check_port #check if we already have the correct port or need 22
  - role: sshd #Set Port to 2222 and restart sshd
  - role: check_port #check the port again, after it has been changed
  - role: install_apps
  - role: configure_apps
```

Error message:

with `delegate_to` for the task `Check backend port 2222`:

```
fatal: [example_cloud_host01 -> ansible@123.123.123.123]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 123.123.123.123 port 22: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}
```

This confuses me, because I expect the delegation host to use the same `ansible_ssh_port` as the target host.

Without `delegate_to` for task `Check backend port 2222` and `Check backend port 22`:

```
fatal: [example_cloud_host01]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "elapsed": 5, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for example_cloud_host01:2222"}
fatal: [example_cloud_host01]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"}, "changed": false, "elapsed": 5, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for example_cloud_host01:22"}
```

I have no idea why this happens. If I try the connection manually, it works fine.

**What I tried so far**:

- I played around with `delegate_to`, `vars`, ... as mentioned above.
- I wanted to see if I can provide `delegato_to` with the proper port 2222 for the jump host.
- I wanted to see if can run this without `delegate_to` (since it should automatically use the proxy command to run on the jump host anyway).

Neither way gave me a solution on how to connect to my second tier servers after changing the SSH port.

Right now, I split the playbook into two

1. deploy sshd config with port 22
2. run our full deploy afterwards on port 2222

Comment: Then for your question, at a really first glance, I would do `delegation_host: example_jumphost`, in your inventory. And then have the `ansible_ssh_port: 2222`, on that host in the inventory. It is not clear in your question if the jump host should be addressed in ssh via port 2222 too, this said.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the fluff part - didn't know that. Regarding the delegate_to with example_jumphost: I tried to circumvent this, because i didn't want to run the tasks on the jumphost as well. In this use case it is only necessary to jump through it. Is there a way to add the jumphost to the inventory without running tasks on it? I have a bunch of projects to manage, each with their unique jumphost... so i would need to make this as flexible as possible :)

Comment: _I tried to circumvent this, because i didn't want to run the tasks on the jumphost_ > which is not clear in your question because you changed every IPs with `123.123.123.123`, which falsely made me thing that you were indeed wanting to delegate to that machine.

Comment: And to clarify the jumphost: i set the ssh port on global inventory level and run my deployment initially on the jumphost alone, to get it up and running. after that, the jumphost is always / only reachable through port 2222 and mostly just used to tunnel ssh to our machines. so it should only be used with port 2222.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following (I somewhat tested this with fake values in the inventory using localhost as a jumphost to check ports on localhost as well)

*Edit: modified my examples to somewhat try to show you a way after your comments on your question an on this answer*

**Inventory**

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_port: 2222

proxies:
  vars:
    ansible_user: ansible
  hosts:
    example_jumphost1:
      ansible_host: 123.123.123.123
    example_jumphost2:
      ansible_host: 231.231.231.231
    # ... and more jump hosts ...

cloud_hosts:
  vars:
    jump_vars: "{{ hostvars[jump_host] }}"
    ansible_ssh_common_args: '-oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -q {{ jump_vars.ansible_user }}@{{ jump_vars.ansible_host }} -p {{ jump_vars.ansible_shh_port | d(22) }}"'
  children:
    cloud_hosts_north:
      vars:
        jump_host: example_jumphost1
      hosts:
        example_cloud_host01:
        example_cloud_host02:
        # ... and more ...
    
    cloud_hosts_south:
      var:
        jump_host: example_jumphost2
      hosts:
        example_cloud_host03:
        example_cloud_host04:
        # ... and more ...

    # ... and more cloud groups ...
```

**Tasks to check ports**.

```yaml
- name: "Check backend inventory configured port {{ ansible_ssh_port }}"
  wait_for:
    port: "{{ ansible_ssh_port }}"
    state: "started"
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    connect_timeout: "5"
    timeout: "5"
  delegate_to: "{{ jump_host }}"
  ignore_errors: true
  register: ssh_port

- name: "Check backend default ssh port if relevant"
  wait_for:
    port: "22"
    state: "started"
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    connect_timeout: "5"
    timeout: "5"
  delegate_to: "{{ jump_host }}"
  ignore_errors: true
  register: ssh_port_default
  when: ssh_port is failed

- name: "Set backend SSH port to 22 if we did not change it yet"
  set_fact:
    ansible_ssh_port: 22
  when:
    - ssh_port_default is not skipped
    - ssh_port_default is success
```

Please note that if checks for ports `22`/`2222` both fail, your configured port will still be `2222` but any later task will obviously fail. You might want to fail fast after checks for those relevant hosts:

```yaml
- name: "Fail host if no port is available"
  fail:
    msg:
      - "Host {{ inventory_hostname }}" does not have"
      - "any ssh port available (tested 22 and 2222)"
  when:
    - ssh_port is failed
    - ssh_port_default is failed
```

With this in place, you can use different targets on your play to reach the relevant hosts:

- For jump hosts

  - Run on a single bastion host: e.g. `hosts: example_jumphost1`
  - Run on all bastion hosts: `hosts: proxies`
- For cloud hosts

  - Run on all cloud hosts: `hosts: cloud_hosts`
  - Run on a single child group: e.g. `hosts: cloud_hosts_north`
  - Run on all cloud hosts except a subgroup: e.g. `hosts: cloud_hosts:!cloud_hosts_south`

For more see [ansible patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html)

Comment: Thanks - can this be run without having the jumphost in the inventory while running? I'm asking because i want to run the deployment tasks only for the specific target server and not on the jumphost as well (it should at this point be already fully deployed). I only would need to delegate_to the jumphost for the port check and nothing else....

Comment: In your play, `hosts: cloud_hosts` will only run the (pre|post)tasks/roles.... against the relevant hosts. Done.

Comment: this solved the issue and my misunderstandings. marked as solution! i had a misunderstanding on how ansible runs the playbook with the provided inventory. and i also had issues with using the automation platform (some vars were behaving randomly when provided through surveys, once i ran them without the survey, all was fine....)

Comment: @TheAlcesh Just edited to add some pattern examples and refactor to have multiple jump_hosts and related groups. Hope it helps

Comment: This answer goes 110% with your edits. I was already changing our inventory according to your example for all of our projects. I was also able to run a bunch of tests and verify that this works fine and stable for all our systems. The next step is to implement your idea for failing when "nothing is available"! The last thing i have to check is how the jumphosts work as a target with this solution. i might have to write an alternate version without delegate_to for them. We will see. Thanks again.